# Problem with 2 Variables passing as false when they should be true

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have two variables that I am running in my code:

```js
$AL = ('C'+DomeLensArray[i]+'LargeArray');
$AS = ('C'+DomeLensArray[i]+'SmallArray');
```

Now, these variables per a console log give me C3LargeArray & C3SmallArray if DomeLensArray[i] equals 3 (also works for 1/2/4/5 as that has been proven).

However, these are coming through as false when I can visibly see the Length in the array which the console log tells me should be the value for $AS and $AL

```js
(jQuery.inArray(Va_LENG,$AL) != -1)
(jQuery.inArray(Va_LENG,$AS) != -1)
```

Here are the arrays:

```js
var C1LargeArray =      ['9','9B','10','10B']
var C1SmallArray =      ['8B','10C']
var C2LargeArray =      ['6','7','8','8B','10','10C']
var C2SmallArray =      ['4B','5','5B','6B','7B','9','9B','10B']
var C3LargeArray =      ['4','6B','7B','8','10B','10C']
var C3SmallArray =      ['3','5','7','9']
var C4LargeArray =      ['5B','6','7','7B','8','8B','9B','10','10C']
var C4SmallArray =      ['4B','5','6B','9','10B']
var C5LargeArray =      ['9','9B','10','10B']
var C5SmallArray =      ['8B','10C']
```

so if we are looking for a length of 6B it should be coming up true for C2SmallArray, C3LargeArray & C4SmallArray as it loops through the 5 different C sections...but it always returns ""when I do this...

```js
$CL = (jQuery.inArray(Va_LENG,$AL) != -1) ? "Large Pass as $AL = " + $AL : (jQuery.inArray(Va_LENG,$AS) != -1) ? "Small Pass as $AS = " + $AS : "";
console.log("$CL is: " + $CL);
```

Thoughts?

Comment: Your `$AL` and `$AS` are **string values**. There is no reason and no mechanism why these **string values** suddenly and automagically would take on the the contents of your local array variables, just because these variables happen to have the same names as what is in your string values.

Comment: As noted above.  Solution is to change `$AL = ('C'+DomeLensArray[i]+'LargeArray');` to `$AL = window['C'+DomeLensArray[i]+'LargeArray'];` (or whatever object/namespace your arrays actually reside in, as surely it's not global...)